# Why is the max size of byte[] 2 GB - 57 B?

Tags: .net, arrays, limits

On my 64-bit machine, this C# code works:

```
new byte[2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 57]
```

but this one throws an `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
new byte[2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 56]
```

Why?

I understand that the maximum size of a managed object is 2 GB and that the array object I'm creating contains more than the bytes I want. Namely, there is 4 bytes (or 8?) for the syncblock number, 8 bytes for MethodTable reference and 4 bytes for the size of the array. That's 24 bytes including padding, so why can't I allocate an array with 2G - 24 bytes? Is the maximum size really *exactly* 2 GB? If that's the case, what is the rest of 2 GB used for?

Note: I don't actually need to allocate an array with 2 million of bytes. And even if I did, 56 bytes is negligible overhead. And I could easily work around the limit using custom `BigArray<T>`.

Comment: The MethodTable reference would be 8 bytes on 64 bits and in addition to that there may be padding to align.

Comment: @Brian, right, I forgot the reference has to be 64-bit too. I have edited the question, but the question still holds.

Comment: Upper limit on an int value perhaps? a byte[] can't exceed int maxvalue i would imagine (given an integer element index).

Comment: @Brad, `int.MaxValue` is 2G - 1, so that doesn't explain it.

Comment: @svick: As always [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367320/what-is-the-exact-maximum-limit-of-elements-in-an-array/5367331#5367331) has an answer to a .net question similar. (MSDN mentioning this upper limit can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: could just be that you don't have enough free RAM.  How much memory do you have in your system, and how many processes are running?

Comment: @Neil, the actual RAM should be relevant here, since I have pagefile turned on. I can allocate 11 of the almost 2G arrays, the 12th attempt throws OOM.

Comment: @Brad, Jon's result is exactly the same as mine (2G - 57), but even he doesn't explain why.

Comment: This allocates from the Large Object Heap.  That one probably allocates directly from the low-fragmentation heap in Windows (depending on your operating system).  You need to add the overhead that the Windows memory manager adds to heap blocks in the LFH.  Size is about right.

Comment: Here is a detailed discussion about .NET array overhead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array I don't think this is particularly interesting discussion however as it is an implementation detail. Unless you are writing an implementation of the .NET Framework, of course.

Comment: @Can, that was really interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need 56 bytes of overhead. It is actually 2,147,483,649-1 *minus* 56 for the maximum size. That's why your *minus* 57 works and *minus* 56 does not.

As [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367320/what-is-the-exact-maximum-limit-of-elements-in-an-array/5367331#5367331) says here:

> However, in practical terms, I don't
>   believe any implementation supports
>   such huge arrays. The CLR has a
>   per-object limit a bit short of 2GB,
>   so even a byte array can't actually
>   have 2147483648 elements. A bit of
>   experimentation shows that on my box,
>   the largest array you can create is
>   new byte[2147483591]. (That's on the
>   64 bit .NET CLR; the version of Mono
>   I've got installed chokes on that.)

See also this [InformIT article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=659) on the same subject. It provides the following code to demonstrate the maximum sizes and overhead:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    AllocateMaxSize<byte>();
    AllocateMaxSize<short>();
    AllocateMaxSize<int>();
    AllocateMaxSize<long>();
    AllocateMaxSize<object>();
  }

  const long twogigLimit = ((long)2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) - 1;
  static void AllocateMaxSize<T>()
  {
    int twogig = (int)twogigLimit;
    int num;
    Type tt = typeof(T);
    if (tt.IsValueType)
    {
      num = twogig / Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    }
    else
    {
      num = twogig / IntPtr.Size;
    }

    T[] buff;
    bool success = false;
    do
    {
      try
      {
        buff = new T[num];
        success = true;
      }
      catch (OutOfMemoryException)
      {
        --num;
      }
    } while (!success);
    Console.WriteLine("Maximum size of {0}[] is {1:N0} items.", typeof(T).ToString(), num);
  }
}
```

Finally, the article has this to say:

> If you do the math, you’ll see that
>   the overhead for allocating an array
>   is 56 bytes. There are some bytes left
>   over at the end due to object sizes.
>   For example, 268,435,448 64-bit
>   numbers occupy 2,147,483,584 bytes.
>   Adding the 56 byte array overhead
>   gives you 2,147,483,640, leaving you 7
>   bytes short of 2 gigabytes.

**Edit:**

But wait, there's more!

Looking around and talking with Jon Skeet, he pointed me to an article he wrote on [Of memory and strings](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx). In that article he provides a table of sizes:

```
Type            x86 size            x64 size
object          12                  24
object[]        16 + length * 4     32 + length * 8
int[]           12 + length * 4     28 + length * 4
byte[]          12 + length         24 + length
string          14 + length * 2     26 + length * 2
```

Mr. Skeet goes on to say:

> You might be forgiven for looking at
>   the numbers above and thinking that
>   the "overhead" of an object is 12
>   bytes in x86 and 24 in x64... but
>   that's not quite right.

and this:

> - There's a "base" overhead of 8 bytes per object in x86 and 16 per
>     object in x64... given that we can
>     store an Int32 of "real" data in x86
>     and still have an object size of 12,
>     and likewise we can store two Int32s
>     of real data in x64 and still have an
>     object of x64.
> - There's a "minimum" size of 12 bytes and 24 bytes respectively. In
>     other words, you can't have a type
>     which is just the overhead. Note how
>     the "Empty" class takes up the same
>     size as creating instances of
>     Object... there's effectively some
>     spare room, because the CLR doesn't
>     like operating on an object with no
>     data. (Note that a struct with no
>     fields takes up space too, even for
>     local variables.)
> - The x86 objects are padded to 4 byte boundaries; on x64 it's 8 bytes
>     (just as before)

and finally Jon Skeet responded to a [question I asked of him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367320/what-is-the-exact-maximum-limit-of-elements-in-an-array/5367331#5367331) in another question where he states (in response to the [InformIT article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=659) I showed him):

> It looks like the article you're
>   referring to is inferring the overhead
>   just from the limit, which is
>   **silly** IMO.

So to answer your question, actual overhead is **24 bytes** with **32 bytes** of spare room, from what I gather.

Comment: But *why* is it 56 bytes? What's stored in them? Also, `Marshal.SizeOf()` doesn't tell you the actual size of the object, only the size of the object if you marshaled it.

Comment: @svick: See this about Overhead of .NET arrays (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array)

Comment: @svick: See the definition of Marshal.Sizeof at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx)

Comment: the doc actually says exactly what I'm saying: “The size of the specified type in **unmanaged** code.” For example, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(bool))` returns 4, but I'm still able to allocate `new bool[almost2G]`, which means the actual size of `bool` is just one byte.

Comment: @svick: I found an obscure article on Hash Tables that may have your answer: "16 bytes overhead, 20 bytes array overhead, 8 bytes for pointer to array, 8 bytes per reference to each array entry, 4 bytes for M, 4 bytes for N, 4 bytes for padding" (http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/)

Comment: @svick: I think because boolean is non-blittable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx that is why you are correct that you must use sizeof not Marshal.sizeof, otherwise for byte it is ok, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @0A0D, that article seems to about Java, but even then, `byte[]`  doesn't contain any array pointers, M or N. I think that's just how the hash table is implemented.

Comment: @svick: oops just realized that.

Comment: @svick: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676249/tupleint-int-versus-int2-memory-usage/4676309#4676309

Comment: Spare room? What's that? Why can't I put my bytes in there?

Comment: @svick: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array

Answer (score 3):

One thing is for sure is that you cannot have an odd number of bytes, it is usually in multiples of the native word size which is 8bytes on a 64 bit process.  So you could be adding another 7 bytes to the array.

Comment: It's usually in multiples of native word sizes. So for 64-bit process, that would be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually find this limit explicitly set and verified in .net source code, and it provides some insight on why this was done (efficient implementation of advanced range check elimination):

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b42188a8143f3c7971a7ab1c735e31d8349e7991/src/coreclr/vm/gchelpers.cpp

```
inline SIZE_T MaxArrayLength()
{
    // Impose limits on maximum array length to prevent corner case integer overflow bugs
    // Keep in sync with Array.MaxArrayLength in BCL.
    return 0X7FFFFFC7;
}
...

if ((SIZE_T)cElements > MaxArrayLength())
    ThrowOutOfMemoryDimensionsExceeded();
```